# mvc foolproof validation client side script not showing until after form submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using foolproof on a couple question in an MVC 3 for.  Specifically I have radio buttons with a textarea, if the radio button 'Yes' is selected, then the textarea can not be empty. I have other validation on some fields, using regular 'Required' attribute and those work fine, but the 'RequiredIfTrue' attributes do not validate on the client side.  So if I fill in all the fields so they will validate, then click Yes on a radio but leave the corresponding textarea empty, then submit, the form hits the server instead of validating client side.  I also noticed when Viewing the Source in the browser, the 'RequiredIfTrue' attributes are not added to the HTML until after the form is submitted.

I am using a ViewModel for this project, and that seems to be the problem.  CUrrently the attributes are on the properties, which are in a model, then I refer to that model in the ViewModel and pass the ViewModel to the View.  But if I put the properties directly in the ViewModel, it works correctly.  I don't want the properties in hte ViewModel , because wouldn't I then need to add some kind of mapping code to the ViewModel so the properties are associated with the correct model/table?

These are the scripts included in the project:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/mvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css")" rel="Stylesheet"" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript""></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/HistoryArrayTables.js")" type="text/javascript""></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is part of the model:

```
using Foolproof;

namespace EligibityForm.Models
{
[MetadataType (typeof(HistoryMetadata))]
public partial class History
{
}

public class HistoryMetadata
{

    [StringLength(2000)]
    [RequiredIfTrue("HasComment", ErrorMessage="Please enter an explanation")]
    [Display(Name = "Have you EVER been subject to a lawsuit?")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public bool HasComment { get; set; }
}
```

And here is part of the ViewModel:

```
using Foolproof;

namespace EligibityForm.Models.CompositeModels
{
    public class HistoryViewModel
    {
        public History HistoryModel { get; set; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: put the data annotations on the viewmodel, that's where they belong